# How to set more than one fonts on a tag to display text?

Tags: html, css

Ok, I have php project with sqlite3 database.
In message table  the messages are stored in many langauages and I want to display the messages according to relevant fonts like this.

```
<?php
.....
echo $msg;// I don't know in which language is this msg..
......
```

I want to display in the message with an english font if message is in English.
Or display it with a hindi font if the message stored is in Hindi.

If it is possible then how?

Comment: Please explain that further - what have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: You PHP tag was being mistaken for HTML `<tag`  select the code and push ctrl+k to format it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Or if the language changes in the same `<span>` then you could use *`font-family stacking`* by specifying multiple families for the same `<span>` or `class`.

Sample code below:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Tamma|Laila');
.myClass {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", "Scheherazade", "PMingLiU", "MingLiU", "SimSum-18030, SimHei", "Doulos SIL", "Baloo Tamma", "Laila"
}
```

```html
<span class="myClass"> 欢迎 歡迎 Καλοσωρίσατε اهلا وسهلا Добро пожаловать Kudual ಸಮಯದ हमारे</span>
```

**Solution 2:**
font-family stacking might lead to slow rendering as the browser has to go from one font-family to next. So It's better if you do this with language attribute `<span class="xyz" lang="ar">` if you know the language that the span will contain and you are sure the language will never change. This way the browser directly goes to the specified font.

Code Sample below from [w3.org/qa-css-lang](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang) you can read more there:

```css
body   {font-family: "Times New Roman",serif;}
:lang(ar)  {font-family: "Scheherazade",serif; 
                 font-size: 120%;}
:lang(zh-Hant)  {font-family: Kai,KaiTi,serif;}
:lang(zh-Hans)  {font-family: DFKai-SB,BiauKai,serif;}
:lang(din)  {font-family: "Doulos SIL",serif;}
```

```html
<p>It is polite to welcome people in their own language:</p>
<ul>
    <li lang="zh-Hans">欢迎</li>
    <li lang="zh-Hant">歡迎</li>
    <li lang="el">Καλοσωρίσατε</li>
    <li lang="ar">اهلا وسهلا</li>
    <li lang="ru">Добро пожаловать</li>
    <li lang="din">Kudual</li>
</ul>
```

I hope it helps;

Peace 🖖

Comment: @Viliyam Vasava just use the second solution of font-family stacking. font-family: "Arial","Laila","Baloo Tamma" here browser will first try Arial, then it'll try Laila font then it'lll try Baloo Tamma. If your website contains most data in English specify an english font first, then Hindi, then Kannada, Gujarati etc.

Comment: @Viliyam Vasava just use the second solution of font-family stacking. font-family: "Arial","Laila","Baloo Tamma" here browser will first try Arial, then it'll try Laila font then it'lll try Baloo Tamma. If your website contains most data in English specify an english font first, then Hindi, then Kannada, Gujarati etc.